# Ubuntu drive partition after installing Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I am using Toshiba Satellite C660 laptop and I moved from Windows 8.1 to Ubuntu. I may have made some mistake during installation as before installing ubuntu I had 4 partitions but after it, only one partition with the size equals to the size of hard drive. Is it possible to create partitions as this is the only partition as of now. What tools will be required and please provide with the terminal codes that needs to be used.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@devansh. Brother you didn't make any mistake if you think why there is only one partition. In Ubuntu there is only one partition called the Home or the root unlike that of Windows in which you can partition your hard drive upto a maximum of 4 drives. I don't think if you can partition after installation but there is a step to logically partition your volume size before installation. I think it will be clear now

Comment: thanks buddy for your help. If that is the case then I'll consider a re-installation with the partition management during installation itself. Thanks again.